# memory leak of inline function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a inline function defined as following:

```
inline string Change(char *pointer) {
    string str;
    char temp[32] = "";

    sprintf(temp,"%c:%c:%c:%c:%c:%c", //line 1
        temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],
        temp[3],temp[4],temp[5],
    );

    str = temp;
    return str;
}
```

when I use memory leak tool to check it, it indicates line 1(marked above) is memory leak. 
What is the problem of the above code?

Comment: There's no leak but it doesn't compiler either. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Can you post a complete, minimal example?

Comment: Maybe it does not like the single quote at the end of the first line.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I believe it will be strongly compiler-dependent.

Comment: what is the argument 'pointer' used for? did you intend to use in the sprintf statement? pointer[0]... ?

Comment: @sharptooth: That's questionable. For starters, there's no explicit dynamic allocation in the code, so it's hard to imagine how a leak could come about in the first place.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Well, `std::string` uses dynamic allocation for the string body.

Comment: @sharptooth: Maybe, but you're not supposed to know that. As far as you, the user, are concerned, `std::string` is an opaque library class that Behaves Correctly And Doesn't Leak.

Comment: @sharptooth: As Kerrek says that's opaque. And Not always. Small string optimized version of std::string are not going to need to allocate memory for this string in this situation (especially on 64 bit architectures).

Comment: What tool and what is the exact error message? If we can't reproduce the error and we don;t know the exact message we can only guess. Things like error messages should ALWAYS be quoted (cut and paste).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created fully compilable example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

std::string Change( char * ) {
    std::string str;
    char temp[32] = "";

    sprintf(temp,"%c:%c:%c:%c:%c:%c", //line 1
        temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],
        temp[3],temp[4],temp[5]
    );

    str = temp;
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char a[]={"abaaaaa2"};
    std::cout<<Change(a)<<std::endl;
}
```

When running under valgrind, I get no leaks detected:

```
==16829== 
==16829== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16829==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16829==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==16829== 
==16829== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16829== 
==16829== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16829== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know exactly where is the leak you can use plugins. you can pick out a plugin that will be convenient for you. For me, it is deleaker. There are so many developments in this field!!

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to know exactly where is the leak you can use plugins. you can pick out a plugin >that will be convenient for you. For me, it is deleaker. There are so many developments in >this field!!

Thank. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The code above alone is leak-free. The tool might indicate a leak in either of the two cases:

1. the string returned from teh function is assigned to another string variable somewhere and that other variable is not destroyed before the tool is run - then technically the string body is still allocated at that point and the tool reports it
2. the string body allocator cached the string body block for future reuse and the tool is run before the allocator releases all cached blocks -  then again technically the string body is allocated and the tool reports it.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak only occurs when you acquire free store memory using `new` or `new []` and do not release it back by calling `delete` or `delete[]` respectively.

`std::string` does internally allocate on freestore but you are returning it as return type, And that is not leaking memory.

The code you showed does not use `new` or `new []` so there is no memory leak in the code you show.
The tool you use seems to be misleading. or ou need to show us your **real** code to get an better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The tool is malfunctioning; there's no memory leak there.